# How do I set up a email whitelist using only procmailrc to protect my kids from unwanted email?

Tags: email, parental-controls, procmail

How do I set up a email whitelist using only procmailrc to protect my kids from unwanted email?

I currently us the OS parental controls, but that is only good for the computer it is enabled on.

I understand that as my kids grow up, they'll figure out work arounds to any technical parental restrictions imposed upon them, but I want to at least understand the options that I have until then.

Comment: I've done this for sending reminders to my phone - I'll post the recipe when I can ssh to my server :)

Comment: added the whitelist recipe as promised :)

Comment: Nice stuff. I'll have to try this out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`procmail` can filter by the `From` header, and there are many recipe examples.

```
# This one discards all mail sent from the address below.
:0
* ^From: idiot@somehost.com
/dev/null
```

But don't forget that `procmail` only works with locally delivered mail. It won't affect mailboxes accessed over IMAP or webmail.

Comment: This is a blacklist recipe. Do you know how to do it the opposite? Such as only allow mail from certain addresses.

Comment: Just change the recipe to use `${DEFAULT}` as the mailbox, then add a second recipe that routes the rest to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @RoninTom's answer is simpler and more to the point.

Answer (score 1):

The one I use to send messages from myself to my phone:

```
VERBOSE=off
LOGFILE=/dev/null

# if it comes from a specific address(es), send to my cell
# it's be just as easy to whitelist a domain by adding another `|domain.tld` section to the bracketed regex
:0
* ^From.*[main.email.domain.tld|other.email.domain.tld]
* ^To.*datente
! 0000000000@vtext.com

# push everything else to my normal user
:0 
* .
! mainuser
```

Comment: also note: I intentionally only gather email sent to the one domain, not any others hosted on the same server

Answer (score 1):

I think we have not any solution yet, that exactly solves the initial problem. Therefore, I would like to provide a more explicit approach. Lets suppose, that our whitelist looks like this:

```
white.domain.tld
light.domain.tld
```

Then I would try the following reciept:

```
:0
* !^From.*@white\.domain\.tld
* !^From.*@light\.domain\.tld
/dev/null
```

This would send all emails that are not from somebody@white.domain.tld and not from somebody@light.domain.tld to `/dev/null`. The remaining emails are send to the default destination. Be aware to use `\.` in your pattern if you like to match a single dot. The pattern `.` matches a single character.

If you have a short whitelist, you could try to get an even shorter reciept by combining the patterns:

```
:0
* !^From.*@(white|light)\.domain\.tld
/dev/null
```

Be aware to use `( )` here. Using `[ ]` would be a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all sure where I got this from (I know I didn't write it myself), but I've been using it in a `.procmailrc` for a while now to forward only messages from an address listed in a separate whitelist file to a given target email address:

```
PMDIR=$HOME/Procmail      # Make sure this directory exists!
TARGET=something@example.com

# allow any addresses listed in $PMDIR/whitelist
WHITELIST=$PMDIR/whitelist
FROM_ADDR=`formail -zxFrom: | sed 's/\(.*[^-_\.0-9a-zA-Z]\)\?\([-_\.0-9a-zA-Z]\+@[-_\.0-9a-zA-Z]\+\).*/\2/'`
:0
* ? fgrep -xs "$FROM_ADDR" "$WHITELIST"
! $TARGET
```